# Open a file, split each line into a list, then for each word on each line check to see if the word is in list and if not append it to the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the best way to perform the following? The sample document (hello.txt) contains the following:

```
>>> repr(hello.txt) #show object representations 

Hello there! This is a sample text. \n Ten plus ten is twenty. \n Twenty times two is forty \n 

>>> print(hello.txt) 

Hello There. This is a sample text 
Ten plus ten is twenty 
Twenty times two is forty
```

**To Do:** 
Open a file, split each line into a list, then for each word on each line check to see if the word is in list and if not append it to the list

```
open_file = open('hello.txt')
lst = list() #create empty list 

for line in open_file:     
    line = line.rstrip()   #strip white space at the end of each line 
    words = line.split()   #split string into a list of words 

    for word in words:
        if word not in words:
            #Missing code here; tried 'if word not in words', but then it produces a empty list 
            lst.append(word) 

lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

**Output from above code:**

```
['Hello', 'Ten', 'There', 'This', 'Twenty', 'a', 'forty', 'is', 'is', 'is', 'plus', 'sample', 'ten', 'text', 'times', 'twenty', 'two']
```

The 'is' string is present 3 times when it should be present only once. I'm stuck with figuring out how to write code for checking each word on each line to see if the word is in list and if not append it to the list..

**Desired output:**

```
['Hello', 'Ten', 'There', 'This', 'Twenty', 'a', 'forty', 'is', 'plus', 'sample', 'ten', 'text', 'times', 'twenty', 'two']
```

Comment: Using a `set` would work and has the advantage of being O(1) for testing `in`, so for a large number of words would be much quicker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error lies in these two lines:

```
for word in words:
     if word not in words:
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
for word in words:
     if word not in lst:
```

---

For whatever it is worth, here is how I would write the entire program:

```
import string
result = sorted(set(
    word.strip(string.punctuation)
    for line in open('hello.txt')
    for word in line.split()))
print result
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks! :) (Been starring at it too much that even the simplest of things can't be "seen".

Answer (score 4):

Sets are ideal for unique membership.

Content of `hello.txt`:

```
Hello there! This is a sample text. 
 Ten plus ten is twenty. 
 Twenty times two is forty
```

Code:

```
result = set()

with open('hello.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        temp = [result.add(item) for item in line.strip().split()]

for item in result:
    print(item)
```

Results:

```
text.
Twenty
This
ten
a
sample
times
twenty.
Hello
is
there!
two
forty
plus
Ten
```

You could also modify your code to say `if word not in lst` instead of `if word not in words`, then it would work.

If you want to sort a set... well, sets are unordered, but you can sort the output with `sorted(result)`.

Comment: As order isn't important (it's sorted at the end) then set works, but I'm not a great fan of using a list comprehension just for the `.add()` side effect. Alternative you could just union sets `result |= set(line.strip().split())`

Comment: I know how to get the words out. I need them to have the desired output in a list? I guess I could just feed them back into the list...

Comment: Just use `sorted(result)` to get a sorted list.

Answer (score 1):

**The Solution:**

```
open_file = open('hello.txt') #open file 

lst = list() #create empty list 


for line in open_file:  #1st for loop strip white space and split string into list of words 
    line = line.rstrip()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:  #nested for loop, check if the word is in list and if not append it to the list
        if word not in lst:
            lst.append(word)

lst.sort() #sort the list of words: alphabetically 
print(lst) #print the list of words
```